# How to get `lsblk` to recognise that a disk was taken off the system?

Tags: hard-drive, centos, centos-7, hotswapping

I have a CentOS 7 server with hot-swap disks.
However, if I take out a disk (which is not mounted, and not part of an md RAID, or an LVM) off the server - `lsblk` still shows it.

**What actions (short of a reboot) can I perform so that `lsblk` will not show this phantom disk?**

Comment: Is it still plugged in? If so, that's what it's supposed to do. `lsblk` lists all available block devices, not just those currently in use. Or do you mean you physically unplug the disk and it's still visible with `lsblk`?

Comment: Yes, @Kefka, I physically unplug the disk, and `lsblk` still lists it. `lsblk | wc -l` gives the same results with the disk in or out of the machine.

Comment: Is this disk connected via IDE, SATA, SCSI, SAS, NVMe, USB? Does `dmesg` report any new lines at all when you disconnect the disk, or when you connect it again?